# "Datatable is not a Function" Error When Layout is no longer null

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc

For Ease I have been working with "Layout = null" Whilst coding my page.
Whilst the layout is null, the Datatable and page as a whole works perfectly fine.

However once the null layout tags were removed and the bootstrap layout kicked in, the datatable no longer shows this HTML error:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function

Any help much appreciated!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>Users</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
<link href="~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
<div style="width:90%; margin:0 auto" class="tablecontainer">
    <a class="popup btn btn-primary" href="/home/CreateUser/0" style="margin-bottom:20px; margin-top:20px">Add new User</a>
    <a class="popup btn btn-primary" href="/home/AddUserToSafe/0" style="margin-bottom:20px; margin-top:20px">Add User to Safe</a>
    <table id="CBR-User">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>User ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Surname</th>
                <th>Department ID</th>
                <th>Rank</th>
                <th>Assigned Safes</th>
                <th>Email Address</th>
                <th>Password</th>
                <th>Add User to Safe</th>
                <th>Edit</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var uTable = $('#CBR-User').DataTable({
            "ajax": {
                "url": '/Home/GetUser',
                "type": "get",
                "datatype": "json"
            },
            "columns": [

                { "data": "User_ID", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "FName", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "SName", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "Department_ID", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "Rank", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "Safe_ID", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "Email_Address", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "Password", "autoWidth": true },
                {
                    "data": "User_ID", "width": "50px", "render": function (data) {
                        return '<a class="popup" href="/home/SaveUser/' + data + '">Edit</a>';
                    }
                },
                {
                    "data": "User_ID", "width": "50px", "render": function (data) {
                        return '<a class="popup" href="/home/DeleteUser/' + data + '">Delete</a>';
                    }
                }
            ]
        })
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: may you share what the console of you browser debugging tool shows ?

Comment: @BabakFakhriloo Added

Comment: FYI Users:76 points to : var uTable = $('#CBR-User').DataTable({

Comment: after fully loading of the page, try $("#tableid").DataTable ... in console and see what it prompts.

Comment: It prompts the exact same sadly.. just at Users:formatted:76.. I have no clue why it doesn't see it as a function suddenly

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the script from the CDN hasn't yet loaded by the time the DOM is loaded with `$(document).ready()`.

You could try instead use:

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
    // DataTable code here
});
```

Another option would be to use the `defer` attribute on the `script` tag.

> Scripts with the defer attribute will prevent the DOMContentLoaded event from firing until the script has loaded and finished evaluating. - [Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script)

Comment: Sadly no luck with that attempt

Comment: You should check your network tab in the browser's developer console to see if the CDN isn't loading for some reason.

I tested the code locally and on [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QPGdRN) which worked when I removed the other script dependencies.

Comment: I added both the defer and the code suggested instead of the: $(document).ready(function () {     (And the script tag above it) only... but the error shown is the one I have just uploaded now...

Comment: Sure, but what does the network tab show? Is the `jquery.dataTables.min.js` file loading correctly?

Comment: I have added a screenshot in case I've missed something, but all seem fine on the Network front? I must admit it's baffling me entirely!

Comment: Yes, very odd. I'd try remove the other libraries one by one and see if one of them is causing the conflict somehow

Comment: I have removed each library to find a single weak link but to no avail.. I believe they are all in correct order too (since they work when format is null)

Comment: I don't really have anything else I can suggest. You see it working on the (codepen)[https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QPGdRN], correct? If you do then there's something overwriting jQuery alias. You could try `$.noConflict()` then use `jQuery` directly to see if you can access anything

Answer (score 0):

So I found the answer to this. And it was annoyingly simple!
There was a shared layout view file. Once I removed the stylesheets from the view and put them in the shared layout view instead. It all worked! It ended up being a clash of stylesheets in the end.

Comment: Are you sure? Stylesheets have no effect on JavaScript

Comment: 100%. I don't think it was the Stylesheet that was the core error, but more the fact that they were clashing with the shared layout view where they were and that must have done something to how the code was loaded.